# Android xml layout changes upon orientation

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

When a certain button is pressed, the `xml` layout which started out at `activity_main` is changed to `graphing`.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    mode = selectedMode;

    if (mode.equals("Graphing"))
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.graphing);
    }
}
```

But when the user is in that layout and changes orientation, the `graphing` layout reverts back to `activity_main`. The troubling issue is that I have both the necessary layouts for `layout` and `layout-land`.

*XML*:

```
layout
    activity_main
    graphing
layout-land
    activity_main
    graphing
```

Comment: Bear in mind that orientation change throws Activity lifecycle callbacks starting from _onCreate_ where you need to make sure you set correct layout too/again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you dont try to save instance states :

```
@Override

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);

   /*this line here save that the current orientation is landascepe */
     state.putChar('O','L'); 

}
```

and then check if the bundle is emoty or not if its empty then there is no orentation occur if its not then you get what you saved in the budle as follow:

```
/* here you point to the id of the landscape layout */
     int mode = R.layout.graphing; 

     @Override

     protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

          super.onCreate(bundle);

          if ((bundle != null)

                  && (bundle.getChar('O') != null)) {
              View v=(View)findViewById(mode);
              setContentView(v);

          }

       }
```

you can ref to this links they are so much useful :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 0):

"orientation change throws Activity lifecycle callbacks starting from onCreate" and you are setting the layout as `activity_main` in `onCreate`, and when the user changes the orientation the `onCreate` is fired and the layout is set as `activity_main`. As @Mhmd Salem said you can use the `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)` and `protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` to save and retrieve the state of your activity